why does samesite=strict attribute in cookies restrict anchor links?
I want to add cookies to my website for enhanced security, as I used to use a bad session storage method.
I noticed that there are three options for samesite attribute in cookies. the most secure one is:
the strict option. but the main downgrade to me is the fact that users will have to refresh or login again to access the site properly. and that could get confusing.
Which honestly I'd prefer using the lax option since it does not have this drawback.
But of course this "drawback" was made for a good reason. and I'm not sure when this feature comes to save the day.
I'm guessing it was made incase a user clicks a link like: https://terriblebank.com/transfer?recipient=hackerman&amount=1000.
and lucky for me I don't use get for any sensitive functionality.
so please enlighten me. is my guess correct?

Does this answer your question? What is the point of X-CSRF-TOKEN or X-XSRF-TOKEN, why not just use a strict same site cookie?
